# CSS flex display difference between Chrome/IE and Edge?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a html snippet like below. On Chrome and IE the vertical scrollbar is displayed inside `divSub2`, but in Edge, the vertical scrollbar on `divSub2` does not displayed, instead it's displayed on body. How can I get it work on Edge, like on Chrome or IE?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body,html{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        body{
            display:flex;
            flex-flow:column;
        }
        .divTop{
            height:100px;
            width:100%;
        }
        .divBottom {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .divMain{
            width:100%;
            flex:1;
            background-color:lightblue;

            display:flex;
            flex-flow:column;
        }
        .divSub1{
            height:40px;
            width:100%;
        }
        .divSub2{
            flex:1;
            overflow-y:auto;
            height:100%;
            background-color:aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divTop">
    </div>
    <div class="divMain">
        <div class="divSub1">
        </div>
        <div class="divSub2">
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divBottom">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:
[The vertical scrollbar displayed on body, in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86jC3.png)

Comment: you have used flex properties wrongly here

Comment: @SahilDhir the same code works on IE and chrome, which properties should i set to get it work on Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add attribute `height:0;` on divSub2